# Como saber qual é o primeiro item no loop ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs

Como saber qual é o primeiro item em um loop `ngRepeat`?

Por exemplo, quero adicionar uma classe numa div, quando ela for a primeira do loop.

Exemplo:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['guilherme', 'wallace', 'bigown', 'rray']" ng-class="{'bold' : se_for_o_primeiro_do_loop}">
</div>
```

Comment: Outro negativo? Poderia por gentileza apontar qual é o problema da minha pergunta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variável `$first`. Ele tem como finalidade indicar qual é o primeiro elemento no `ng-repeat`.

Veja:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['guilherme', 'wallace', 'bigown', 'rray']" ng-class="{'bold' : $first}"></div>
```

Você também pode usar o `$last` para indicar o último elemento no `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Para o último seria `$last`?

Comment: Miguel, caraca! tem o `$middle` também! não acredito! Angular é muito top!

Comment: Sim, é muito util @WallaceMaxters ... Tem uma vasta comunidade. Não é à toa que existe tanta gente a usar, e tem um enorme apoio online, e boa documentação.. Não há razão para não usar. É mesmo questão de gosto